# SQL join - How to allocate a data from one-to-many mapping problem

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables
TABLE1 with data

| A1 | B1 | C1 | D1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XX | yy | 2010 | 10 |
| XX | zz | 2010 | 20 |

TABLE2 with data

| A1 | C1 | D2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| XX | 2010 | 5 |

I want to join the data in SQL and subtract the XX|2010 combo only once from TABLE1

| A1 | B1 | C1 | D1 | D2 | D1_NEW |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XX | yy | 2010 | 10 | 5 | 5 |
| XX | zz | 2010 | 20 | 5 | 20 |

Is there a way to do this in SQL?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: What did you try so far? I assume it should be possible using a `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Where does the D1_NEW=20 cell come from?

Answer (score 1):

**Oracle**
You can use ROW_NUMBER() OVER() analytic function to define row numbers and then, using CASE expression, do the subtraction just on first row...

```sql
--  S a m p l e   D a t a :
WITH
    tbl_1 AS
        (
            Select 'XX' "A1",  'yy' "B1", 2010 "C1", 10 "D1" From Dual Union All
            Select 'XX' "A1",  'zz' "B1", 2010 "C1", 20 "D1" From Dual 
        ),
    tbl_2 AS
        (
            Select 'XX' "A1", 2010 "C1", 5 "D1" From Dual 
        )
--  
--  M a i n   S Q L :
Select
    t1.A1, t1.B1, t1.C1, t1.D1, t2.D1 "D2", 
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By t1.A1, t1.C1 Order By t1.B1) = 1 
         THEN t1.D1 - t2.D1 
    ELSE t1.D1 END "D1_NEW"
From
    tbl_1 t1
Left Join
    tbl_2 t2 ON(t2.A1 = t1.A1) 
--
--  R e s u l t :
--  A1 B1         C1         D1         D2     D1_NEW
--  -- -- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
--  XX yy       2010         10          5          5 
--  XX zz       2010         20          5         20
```